# Setting width as a percentage using jQuery

Tags: jquery, width

How can I set the width of a div as a percentage using jQuery?

Answer (score 140, accepted):

Using the [width](http://api.jquery.com/width/) function:

```
$('div#somediv').width('70%');
```

will turn:

```
<div id="somediv" />
```

into:

```
<div id="somediv" style="width: 70%;"/>
```

Comment: i got width in a variable! How can i make it to %width??

Comment: @hemnathmouli jQuery("div#somediv").width(myvar + "%");

Comment: I have an element with a width of 24%, setting the width as you suggest to 11% gives me a width of 33% instead. I thought it was adding the width to the existing width but as you can see 24 + 11 = 35 and not 33. Could you be having any idea as to why this happens?

Comment: I know this is an old post, but I just ran into it since it's the first result on google. I've noticed that css() function is a bit faster that width(), maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: I was trying to set a width using `.width("20%")` however the element kept getting set to `width: 24%`. After digging through the docs, turns out this is related to the CSS `box-sizing` property. Using `.css({'width':"20%"})` will avoid this adjustment.

Answer (score 19):

Here is an alternative that worked for me:

```
$('div#somediv').css({'width': '70%'});
```

Answer (score 15):

Hemnath

If your variable is the percentage:

```
var myWidth = 70;
$('div#somediv').width(myWidth + '%');
```

If your variable is in pixels, and you want the percentage it take up of the parent:

```
var myWidth = 140;
var myPercentage = (myWidth / $('div#somediv').parent().width()) * 100;
$('div#somediv').width(myPercentage + '%');
```