# Reducing font size in table so the table fits inside a div

Tags: jquery

I have a fixed width div that has a table that is wider than the div.
What i wish to do is shrink the table text so it fits inside the div.

setting the width as a percentage as per [This Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2124351/set-width-in-percentage-using-jquery) Setting table width to 100% isn't working.

The following code will work but how do i automate it ie calculate FontSize?

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href=/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css">
     <script src="/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>    
    <script src="/ui/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>    
    <script src="/ui/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>    
    <script src="/ui/jquery.ui.mouse.js"></script>    
<script src="/ui/jquery.ui.resizable.js"></script>    
<style>
  #narrorColumn{
    width: 250px;
  }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
 function ShrinkTable(){
var FontSize = 6;

function ShrinkTable(){
   var TabWidth = $("#tbl").width();
   var DivWidth= $("#narrowColumn");
   if (DivWidth <= TabWidth)
    {
      $("#tbl").css('font-size', FontSize);
    }
}


</script>

</head>
<body onLoad="ShrinkTable()" >
<div id = "narrorColumn" >
<table id="tbl" border="10">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>First Column</th>
<th>Second Column</th>
<th>Third Column</th>
<th>Forth Column</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>Some Random text here</td>
<td>Some Random text here</td>
<td>Some Random text here</td>
<td>Some Random text here</td>
 </tr>
<tr>
<td>Mary Had a little lamb</td>
<td>Mary Had a little lamb</td>
<td>Mary Had a little lamb</td>
<td>Mary Had a little lamb</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Humpty Dumpty sat on a wall</td>
<td>Humpty Dumpty sat on a wall</td>
<td>Humpty Dumpty sat on a wall</td>
<td>Humpty Dumpty sat on a wall</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Hay diddle diddle the kat and the fiddle</td>
<td>Hay diddle diddle the kat and the fiddle</td>
<td>Hay diddle diddle the kat and the fiddle</td>
<td>Hay diddle diddle the kat and the fiddle</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
<div> <input type=button value="Make Big" onClick="$('#tbl').makeBig()">
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: hmm... font size is 6 what?  6px, 6pt, 6em?  think you need to add the unit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the code above will work.
It has some of typo mistakes.

I'm not sure if this will affect the performance a lot but what I think you can try to reduce the font size until the size of the table is smaller than table width.

See below code:

```
<div id = "narrorColumn" >
<table id="tbl" border="10">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>First Column</th>
<th>Second Column</th>
<th>Third Column</th>
<th>Forth Column</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>Some Random text here</td>
<td>Some Random text here</td>
<td>Some Random text here</td>
<td>Some Random text here</td>
 </tr>
<tr>
<td>Mary Had a little lamb</td>
<td>Mary Had a little lamb</td>
<td>Mary Had a little lamb</td>
<td>Mary Had a little lamb</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Humpty Dumpty sat on a wall</td>
<td>Humpty Dumpty sat on a wall</td>
<td>Humpty Dumpty sat on a wall</td>
<td>Humpty Dumpty sat on a wall</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Hay diddle diddle the kat and the fiddle</td>
<td>Hay diddle diddle the kat and the fiddle</td>
<td>Hay diddle diddle the kat and the fiddle</td>
<td>Hay diddle diddle the kat and the fiddle</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
<div> <input type=button value="Make Big" onClick="$('#tbl').makeBig()">
</div>​
```

CSS

```
#narrorColumn{
    width: 300px; /* You can play around with this width to test it */
    background-color:#ccc;
}

#tbl {
width:100%;
    font-size:55px;
}
​
```

javascript

```
function ShrinkTable() {
    var FontSize = parseInt($("#tbl").css('font-size').replace('px', ''),10);
    var TabWidth = $("#tbl").width();
    var DivWidth = $("#narrorColumn");
    /****REMOVED equal sign(=) ****/
    if (parseInt(DivWidth.css('width').replace('px', ''),10) < TabWidth) {
        $("#tbl").css('font-size', FontSize - 4 + 'px'); /* you can change 4 with any number, the smaller is better but it may require more loop */
        //Shrink the font while div width is less than table width
        ShrinkTable();
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    ShrinkTable();
});​
```

I hope it answer your question. See jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/v2g86/2/)

Comment: Hi It seems this only works on IE In Firefox if font-size has been set in css for the table then within the code FontSize decreases but TabWidth remains constant causing an endless loop

Comment: could you setup sample in the jsfiddle? I tried in chrome only when write the code but normally if it works on chrome it should work on firefox as well.

Comment: I just opened your fiddle in FF 12.0 & the table remains large in IE it shrinks.