# I have tried to use the jQuery css function to change the width of element with a class, am I using the right function?

Tags: jquery, css

Is it possible to change the value of width below using jQuery

```
 <div style="width:75%" id="twitter" class="bar"></div>
 <div style="width:75%" id="other2" class="bar"></div>
 <div style="width:75%" id="something" class="bar"></div>
```

I have tried

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
   $('#twitter').css({
   "width":"5%",
   });
)};
```

Here is my jsfiddle

```
http://jsfiddle.net/LSwwB/1/
```

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2124351/set-width-in-percentage-using-jquery

Comment: Lose the trailing comma, IE won't like that.

Comment: @PeterSzymkowski Should I delete this question?? I don't want to post a duplicate.

Comment: @user1530249 Yes, please. Also please read [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Comment: @PeterSzymkowski questions containing answers cannot be deleted. Just closed and than deleted if needed.

Answer (score 3):

You had a couple errors in your code. Fixed on http://jsfiddle.net/LSwwB/3/.

Line 3: no comma after the last property.
Line 5: `)};` should be `});`

Answer (score 0):

That should work fine (with the syntax fixes posted by others). Slighly simpler is jQuery's Width function: http://api.jquery.com/width/#width2

```
$('#twitter').width('5%');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   jQuery(function($) {
        $('#twitter').css({width:"5%"}); // <-- extra ','
   });  // <-- instead of mustache add a beard to that fella
```