# Set an element as percentage width using a variable?

Tags: jquery

How do you set an element as percentage width using a variable?

```
var progBarValue = $('.days-due').text();

$('.bar').width(progBarValue%);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2124351/set-width-in-percentage-using-jquery

Comment: Nope, not using a variable like here.

Comment: @simple it's still very, very, very similar.

Answer (score 0):

The value is a string, so you just need to append the percent sign to it.

```
var width = parseInt(progBarValue);
if (width > 100)
{
    width = 100;
}

$('.bar').width(width +"%");
```

Comment: Is there a way to limit width to no higher than 100%?