# How to set width in percentage in Jquery

Tags: jquery, css, html, width

```
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery('#allinone_contentSlider_common').allinone_contentSlider({
        skin: 'common',
        width:1000,
        height: 1000,
        autoHideBottomNav:false,
        showPreviewThumbs:false,
        autoHideNavArrows:false,
        thumbsWrapperMarginBottom:-50
    });     
});
```

I am using this code for my complete page slider. I want to rotate my full page with logo and menus, and here in this code I have fixed height and width. I don't want to make it fixed, I want it 100%.

In this code I want to set the width of my page 100. Here height and width are fixed so please give me any suggestions on how I can resolve this problem.

Comment: Try using width:100%, height:100%

Comment: Did u missed it

[set-width-in-percentage-using-jquery][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2124351/set-width-in-percentage-using-jquery

Comment: then just use width:main_width and height:main_height.

Answer (score 6):

You set width using CSS. Now you can change css using jQuery like this.

```
$("#id_of_your_element").css("width", "20%");
```

Comment: where to use this code on place of height and width and id of eleement means allinone_contentSlider_common

Comment: for changing width .. first you need to get the target element somehow.. like here I am getting by Id.. you can check the actual element you want in google chrome or firefox using the developer tools (ctrl+shit+i).

Answer (score 3):

You can set percentage widths and heights simply using:

```
$(elem).width('100%');
$(elem).height('100%');
```

Do note that this will be 100% height and width of its containing parent and not necessarily 100% height and width of your page. If your `#allinone_contentSlider_common` element's parent only has 100px height and width, 100% will reflect those values.

Depending on how this `allinone_contentSlider()` plugin method works, you should simply be able to use:

```
jQuery('#allinone_contentSlider_common').allinone_contentSlider({
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    ...
});
```

Comment: That's not very descriptive. How is it not working? Has the width and height changed? What is the width and height in relation to the parent width and height?

Comment: this height and width reflect the height and width of my complete page its 1000 , 1000 means my page is now of 1000 height and width soi want to make it 100% so that it will not be fixed and adjust according to screen height and width

Comment: In that case, just set it to the width and height of `$(window).width()` and `$(window).height()`. You'll need to make sure to update these values when the window is resized, however. As mentioned in my answer, percentage values are a percentage of the element which contains them. For instance: `<div><span></span></div>` if the `div` was 100px wide and 200px high and the `span` was set to 100% height and width, the span would be 100px wide and 200px high.

Comment: @NaveenKumar no worries. Remember to set the answer which most helped as Accepted to help future visitors. :-)

Comment: hi i need your help i have posted a question please do something if you can here isd the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17079903/jquery-conflict-not-running-two-jquery-in-same-page?noredirect=1#comment24703301_17079903

Comment: @NaveenKumar please remember to set this as the accepted answer, otherwise it appears unanswered.

Comment: @NaveenKumar to mark as accepted you click on the green tick below the post score in the top left.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to check that `allinone_contentSlider` that you are using accepts anything but integers for its `width` option.

If it does - the correct option will be `width: '1000%'` - pay attention to the fact that now it is a string, not an integer.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
jQuery(function() {
var main_height = jQuery(window).height();
var main_width = jQuery(window).width();
jQuery('#allinone_contentSlider_common').allinone_contentSlider({
    skin: 'common',
    width: (main_width/100)*(your_width_in_%),
    height: (main_height/100)*(your_height_in_%),
    autoHideBottomNav:false,
    showPreviewThumbs:false,
    autoHideNavArrows:false,
    thumbsWrapperMarginBottom:-50
});     
});
```

Comment: hii its not working Animesh  i want to set height and width 100% but i have fixed

Comment: then just use width:main_width and height:main_height.

Answer (score 0):

In that case, just set it to the width and height of $(window).width() and $(window).height(). You'll need to make sure to update these values when the window is resized, however. As mentioned in my answer, percentage values are a percentage of the element which contains them. For instance:  if the div was 100px wide and 200px high and the span was set to 100% height and width, the span would be 100px wide and 200px high. – James Donnelly May 30 at 9:11