# Changing JQuery using media queries

Tags: java, jquery, sidenav

I have a sidenav on my page that comes out at 30% page width. I want this to change to 100% page width at the 768px breakpoint. How would I go about doing this using JQuery?

This is my code

```
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "30%";
}

function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
}
```

Comment: Can you post more code or create a fiddle like this one? http://jsfiddle.net/totszwai/j60h38fy/5/  Also, take a look at this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2124351/setting-width-as-a-percentage-using-jquery

Answer (score -1):

```js
            //  your sidebar
            var sidebar = $("aside");
            updateSibarWidth();
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $(window).resize(function() {
                    updateSibarWidth();
                });
            });
            // Function to update the width of the sidebar!
            function updateSibarWidth() {
                if($(window).width() < 768) {
                        sidebar.width("100%") ;
                    } else {
                        sidebar.width("30%") ;
                    }
            }
```

```css
    .rect {
        width:150px;
        height:150px;
        background-color: rgb(21, 181, 202);
    }
```

```html
<body>

        <aside class="rect">sidebar</aside>
       
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
    </body>
```